# No module named 'pydantic.v1' even though pip list see it

Tags: python, pydantic, obsei

I install `obsei[all]` in a venv, then run `python .\example\facebook_example.py`. I get:

[`pydantic.errors.PydanticImportError:` BaseSettings`has been moved to the`pydantic-settings `package`](https://github.com/obsei/obsei/issues/310)

According to [Migration Guide - Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/migration/#continue-using-pydantic-v1-features), I can use

```
pip install "pydantic==1.*"
```

and continue to use the old version by importing `pydantic.v1`. However I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Topic modelling\obsei\example\facebook_example.py", line 4, in <module>
    from obsei.source.facebook_source import FacebookSource, FacebookSourceConfig
  File "D:\Programming\Topic modelling\obsei\.venv\Lib\site-packages\obsei\source\facebook_source.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pydantic.v1 import BaseSettings, Field, PrivateAttr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic.v1'
```

Running `pip list` I get:

```
pydantic                 1.10.13        
pydantic_core            2.10.1
pydantic-settings        2.0.3
```

Why doesn't it recognize that I'm using v1?

My `pip --version` is 23.3.1 from D:\Programming\Topic modelling\obsei.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)

```
pip -V
pip 23.3.1 from D:\Programming\Topic modelling\obsei\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)

python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
D:\Programming\Topic modelling\obsei\.venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

Comment: Does the output pf `pip -V` and `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` match in path???

Comment: Indeed no. The first one points to `obsei\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip`, the second one points to `obsei\.venv\Scripts\python.exe`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: It should be fine, looks like both pip and python are being executed from the virtual environment

Comment: so do you have any idea?

Comment: I think it would be a problem if you had something like 
`D:\Programming\Topic modelling\obsei\.venv\Scripts\python.exe` and `D:\Users\obsei\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pip` because then pip is installing packages on one place and then when you execute `python` the interpreter would look for the packages in a different place. But it looks like you're fine. === I've never used pydantic, are you sure you have to import from `pydantic.v1` and not just `pydantic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the guide you [linked](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/migration/#continue-using-pydantic-v1-features:%7E:text=The%20Pydantic%20V2%20package%20also%20continues%20to%20provide%20access%20to%20the%20Pydantic%20V1%20API%20by%20importing%20through%20pydantic.v1)

> The Pydantic V2 package also continues to provide access to the Pydantic V1 API by importing through pydantic.v1

So

`import from pydantic.v1` is for when you have installed version 2.

Since you have v1 installed you should probably do
`import from pydantic`

Just in case try:

- remove all pydantic packages and install version 2, then try `import from pydantic.v1`
- remove all pydantic packages install v1, then try `import from pydantic`

See which one works for you and keep only 1 version installed.